# Google Mock Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL，never called

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

I have a mocked function that when I run in a unit test with the anything matcher ('_') the unit test fails because GMock can't find a matched function.

Here is my mocked class and function:

```
#include <climits>
extern "C" {
#include <features.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
}

#include <cstring>

#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#define UNW_TDEP_CURSOR_LEN 30

typedef struct unw_word
{
        int a;
}
unw_word_t;

typedef struct unw_cursor
{
        unw_word_t opaque[UNW_TDEP_CURSOR_LEN];
}
unw_cursor_t;

typedef int unw_context_t;

#define TRACE_BACKTRACE_FRAMES       32
#define TRACE_BACKTRACE_FNAME_LENGTH 64


typedef struct trace_backtrace_frame {
    size_t    level;
    void*     address;
    char      function_name[TRACE_BACKTRACE_FNAME_LENGTH];
    uintptr_t function_offset;
} trace_backtrace_frame_t;

typedef struct trace_backtrace {
    pid_t                   pid;
    trace_backtrace_frame_t frames[TRACE_BACKTRACE_FRAMES];
} trace_backtrace_t;


typedef enum trace_backtrace_flags {
    TRACE_BACKTRACE_FLAG_NONE           = 0,
    TRACE_BACKTRACE_FLAG_SIGNAL_HANDLER = 1 << 0, /* Backtrace generated from a signal handler */
} trace_backtrace_flags_t;

class BacktraceLibXInterface{
    public:
        virtual ~BacktraceLibXInterface() {}

        virtual int unw_init_local (unw_cursor_t *c, unw_context_t *ctxt) = 0;
        virtual int unw_getcontext (unw_context_t *ucp)=0;
};


class MockBacktraceLibXInterface : public BacktraceLibXInterface{
public:

MOCK_METHOD2(unw_init_local, int(unw_cursor_t *, unw_context_t *));
MOCK_METHOD1(unw_getcontext, int(unw_context_t *));
};
```

Here is the test function:

```
#include <climits>
extern "C" {
#include <features.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
}

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock/gmock.h"
#include "backtrace_mock.h"

using ::testing::_;
using ::testing::DoAll;
using ::testing::Ge;
using ::testing::NotNull;
using ::testing::Return;
using ::testing::ReturnArg;

using namespace std;
using namespace testing;

#define success 0
#define fail -1

#define UNW_ESUCCESS 0

extern "C" {
int unw_getcontext (unw_context_t *ucp)
{
    (void)ucp;
    
    return success;
}

int unw_init_local(unw_cursor_t *c, unw_context_t *ctxt)
{
    (void)c;
    (void)ctxt;
    
    return success;
}

bool
trace_backtrace_init_local(trace_backtrace_t* bt, const trace_backtrace_flags_t flags)
{
    unw_cursor_t  cursor;
    unw_context_t context;
    //trace_backtrace_clear(bt);

    (void)bt;
    (void)flags;

    if (unw_getcontext(&context) != UNW_ESUCCESS) {
        
        return false;
    }
    
    if (unw_init_local(&cursor, &context) != UNW_ESUCCESS) {

        return false;
    }   
    
    return true;
}
}

//TEST(backtraceTest, trace_backtrace_init_local_test) 
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
    trace_backtrace_t bt;
    memset(&bt, 0, sizeof(bt));
    MockBacktraceLibXInterface MockTestbacktrace;

    EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_getcontext(_))
    .WillOnce(Return(0));

    EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_init_local(_,_))
    .WillOnce(Return(0));   
    
  EXPECT_EQ(1, trace_backtrace_init_local(&bt, TRACE_BACKTRACE_FLAG_NONE));  
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  // The following line must be executed to initialize Google Mock
  // (and Google Test) before running the tests.
  ::testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Here is the failure message:

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_getcontext(_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active


Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_init_local(_,_))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active


[  FAILED  ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from PainterTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] PainterTest.CanDrawSomething

 1 FAILED TEST
```

I don't understand why this is going wrong. How do you use Expect Call

Answer (score 1):

You have an interface `BacktraceLibXInterface` but noone is using it. So mock of that interface is not used either, there are no place where mocked methods are called.

According to your test, function `trace_backtrace_init_local` should accept some instance of `BacktraceLibXInterface` and call its methods. In that case expectations will be met.

Possible solution:

```
bool
trace_backtrace_init_local(BacktraceLibXInterface& lib, trace_backtrace_t* bt, const trace_backtrace_flags_t flags)
{
    unw_cursor_t  cursor;
    unw_context_t context;
    //trace_backtrace_clear(bt);

    (void)bt;
    (void)flags;

    if (lib.unw_getcontext(&context) != UNW_ESUCCESS) {
        
        return false;
    }
    
    if (lib.unw_init_local(&cursor, &context) != UNW_ESUCCESS) {

        return false;
    }   
    
    return true;
}
}

//TEST(backtraceTest, trace_backtrace_init_local_test) 
TEST(PainterTest, CanDrawSomething) {
    trace_backtrace_t bt;
    memset(&bt, 0, sizeof(bt));
    MockBacktraceLibXInterface MockTestbacktrace;

    EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_getcontext(_))
    .WillOnce(Return(0));

    EXPECT_CALL(MockTestbacktrace, unw_init_local(_,_))
    .WillOnce(Return(0));   
    
  EXPECT_EQ(1, trace_backtrace_init_local(MockTestbacktrace, &bt, TRACE_BACKTRACE_FLAG_NONE));  
}
```

Comment: Hi jdfa, thank you very much for your answer. The problem that bothered me for many days has finally been solved. I passed the test here. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi jdfa, is there a way to call a mock function without modifying trace_backtrace_init_local?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible with gmock itself: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html#mocking-free-functions
I know that there are some other libraries for that purpose, you can easily find them. But I have no experience with any of them, so can't suggest any specific.

Comment: OK, I'll take a closer look at these and thank you very much for your answer.